# File Upload Form Field Validation

Tags: javascript, validation

This is a trivial question, but for some reason I am having trouble with it.

I have HTML for uploading a file such as the following.

```
 <input type="file" name="settings">
```

And all I need to do is check when the form is submitted that a value has been selected. 
I dont need help with the code for the form submission, I just need help since I am guessing 
you are unable to validate this as you would other form input fields such as text boxes.

I have tried doing things like...
       `var file = document.getElementById('settings').value;

      if(file.length > 0 == false){

                //give error messsage here`

I know that there should be an easy fix for this but I cant quite figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: you're asking for an element by ID.  your element doesn't have an ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="file" name="field_name" onchange="validate_file_format('field_name','allowed file format as comma separeated')"/>

Ex:
<input type="file" name="sitemap_doc" onchange="validate_file_format('sitemap_doc','doc,pdf')"/>


JS Code:
======
function validate_file_format(field_name, allowed_ext){
    obj1=document.req_form;
    var temp_field= 'obj1.'+field_name+'.value';
    field_value=eval(temp_field);
    if(field_value!=""){
        var file_ext= (field_value.substring((field_value.lastIndexOf('.')+1)).toLowerCase());
        ext=allowed_ext.split(',');
        var allow=0;
        for ( var i=0; i < ext.length; i++) {
                if(ext[i]==file_ext){
                    allow=1;
                }
        }
        if(!allow){
            alert('Invalid File format. Please upload file in '+allowed_ext+' format');        
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why this would not work - as long as you give the input an id:

```
<input type="file" name="settings" id="settings">
```

Answer (score 2):

What about just doing:

```
<input type="file" name="settings" id="settings">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the  code an id attribute with the value "settings". You have a strange if construction.

> if(file.length <= 0) { //error message
>   }